# d3: what to use to draw some net of pipelines?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am wondering what to use as base in d3.js to draw some network of joined pipes (with some interactivity for additional info on joints), maybe even auto-layout but not based on "force" simulation.

Comment: if you have a moment I will write this for you

Comment: yes please, that would be great